# Revert css value to value before pseudo classes

Tags: css

```
<style>
div {
  color: red;
}


button {
  color: yellow;
}

button:hover {
  color: green;
}

button:disabled {
  color: inherit;  /* This sets the color to red but I want yellow */

  /* could do this but it's less flexible */
  color: yellow;
}
</style>
<div>
  <button disabled>Yo</button>
</div>
```

Above explains the problem that I have.  I've tried using inherit, unset, initial but none of them achieve what I want. "inherit" is close but is uses the parent color.  I would like to revert the color back to the original cover when an item is disabled even when its hovered without having to explicitly declare the color in the disabled pseudoclass.

Comment: try attribute styling instead of psedo classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS variable to define your colors and avoid the change inside the pseudo class:

```css
:root {
  --main-color: yellow;
}

div {
  color: red;
}

button {
  color: var(--main-color);
}

button:hover {
  color: green;
}

button:disabled {
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button disabled>Yoooooo</button>
</div>
```

Or make some changes to your selectors. Avoid the hover to be applied to the disabled button and this one will by default keep the initial color:

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

button {
  color: yellow;
}

button:not([disabled]):hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button disabled>Yoooooo</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button >Yoooooo yooo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This achieves it.  Thanks for the clear and clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using this?

> The `:not()` CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a list of selectors.

```
button, button:disabled {
  color: yellow;
}
button:not(:disabled):hover {
  color: green;
}
```

Or

```
button {
  color: yellow;
}
button:not(:disabled):hover {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: no need to add the disable state with the normal state as it's by default ... so you can keep only button with the first rule, and you will have almost the same situation as me :) i used attribute selector and you used the pseudo class ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess you're right, I might be overthinking about it. I didn't see your revision before posting this.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZepyB

```
div {
  color: red;
}

button,
button:disabled {
  /* assign the default colors together */
  color: yellow;
}

button:hover {
  color: green;
}

button:disabled:hover {
  /* then override the disable state separately as needed */
  color: #cc00cc;
}
```

Comment: yes but i guess we have the same issue ... you explicitly specify the second color, i guess he need to not specify any color to keep always the yellow

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but this basic CSS mechanism would be:

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

button, button:hover:disabled {
  color: yellow;
}

button:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Yo</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button disabled>Yo</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button disabled>Yo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i got his issue ... try to hover, the color will change .. and that's why he cannot put them together ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just add ":disabled:hover" to the "button" selector and remove the ":disabled" one:

```
button,
button:hover:disabled {
  color: yellow;
}
```